# How to get the next correlative id from a varchar on .NET?

Tags: mysql, .net

I have a code on a MySQL database like this:

```
MD-54564
MD-54565
MD-54566
```

So I need to get the next code and I trying something like this:

```
string code_select = "SELECT MAX(CAST((SUBSTRING(code,4)) as UNSIGNED)) FROM table WHERE code like 'MD-%'";
DataTable   code = new DataTable();
code = conexion.mySelect(code_select);
num_code = Int32.Parse(code);
num_code = num_code + 1;
code= "MD-" + num_code.ToString();
```

This is giving me `CS1502 error` on the 4th line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add **`** around the `code` to escape the word, since it is a [`keyword`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in MySQL.

The following code is working:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST((SUBSTRING(`code`, 4)) AS UNSIGNED))
FROM table 
WHERE `code` LIKE 'MD-%';
```

Check the Demo: http://rextester.com/WBH92696

Comment: Thanks, that is way better. How can I convert the DataTable result into a String?

Answer (score 0):

```
string code_select = "SELECT MAX(CAST((SUBSTRING(code,4)) as UNSIGNED)) + 1 AS NextNumber FROM table WHERE code like 'MD-%'";
DataTable code = new DataTable();
code = conexion.mySelect(code_select);
DataRow row = code.Rows[0];
reg_num = row["NextNumber"].ToString();
cod_ev = "MD-" + reg_num;
```